# which sentence sounds natural

Tags: grammar, sentence

Which sentences are grammatically correct and which one sounds the most natural to you?

> 1. Speaking English is not as tough as it used to be.
> 2. Speaking English is not tougher than it used to be.
> 3. Speaking English is not tough as before.

Comment: You may not realise that English Language & Usage (EL&U) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. There’s also [ell.se] where you might find some useful information and similar questions.. For further information about what's expected in a question on our EL&U site, see **[Ask]**. :-)

Answer (score -1):

## 1 and 2 are both correct as they stand, though there is a difference between them.

The first implies that speaking English is easier than before, whereas the second indicates that there has been no change in the difficulty.

Sentence 3 is ungrammatical, though adding *as* before tough would fix this and the meaning would be nearly identical to the first.

Comment: It was easy for me to understand.Thank you for explaining in detail.

Comment: When one sentence says "I have lost a million dollars", and another "I haven't won a single dollar", you can't call that a nuance. You must call it two completely different things.

Comment: @RegDwigнt you’re right of course. I’ve amended my answer. From an ESL standpoint though, these are two similar sentences employing a comparative structure. I’ll be more careful with diction in the future.